# Keras Custom loss function to pass argument (numpy array containing Noise learnt) with same batch size as of y_true and y_pred

Tags: loss

I have Implemented a custom loss function which takes in additional Noise ( numpy array) As illustrated below :

```
  def custom_rcae_loss(self):

        N = self.Noise
        lambda_val = self.lamda[0]
        mue = self.mue
        self.batchNo += 1
        index = self.batchNo
        def custom_rcae(y_true, y_pred):
            if(N.ndim >1):
                term1 = keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, (y_pred + N ))
```

The issue is that y_pred is of shape (batch_size, 28,28,1) : 
How can I make sure my Noise is also of the same shape of y_pred? 
 Since I would like to perform (y_pred + Noise).

For instance: If my input is 5983 number of samples with a batch size of 128  There is not the same number of batch_size splits.

How can we address this issue while using keras for making sure Noise is of the same shape of y_pred

Looking forward to suggestions and hints 
Thanks in advance